# Squaring Predictor and Response Variable in Multiple Regression Model

Tags: statistics, regression

If I square both the response variable $(Y)$ and the predictor variable ($x_k$) in a multiple regression model ($y_i = \beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^p x_j\beta_j +\epsilon_i$), should I include both the original predictor $(x_k)$ variable along with the squared predictor ($x_k^2$) variable? Or is this an issue due to multicollinearity?

Comment: The answer depends of your reason for wanting to use squared predicted variable $Y.$ If you are trying to model the relationship is a general quadratic one, then probably best to use both $x$ and $x^2$ unless you get warnings about multi-collinearity. If the relationship btw $x$ and $Y$ seems simpler, then maybe only $x^2.$ // You can always look at residuals from both models and pick the one that works best.

Answer (score 1):

$X^2$ is not a linear transformation of $X$, however $X$ and $X^2$ are in general not independent (uncorrelated) as well, so high multicolineairy is a possible issue. Regarding whether to keep them both or not - not so much a statistical question. IMHO, keeping them both is important as sometimes the very inclusion of $X^2$ stems from the fact that you assume square function with minimum or maximum that is not at $x = 0$, i.e., 
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y|X] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \beta_2 x^2,
$$ 
then 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \mathbb{E}[Y|X]= \beta_1  +2\beta_2x=0,
$$
so you can estimate the value of this extrema point by 
$$
\hat{x}_{ex} = -\frac{\hat{\beta}_1}{2\hat{\beta}_2}.
$$

Comment: Interesting comments on multicolinearity and retaining $X$ along with $X^2$ (which I agree is almost always best practice when feasible) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Here are Minitab plots for four regressions:
$x$-values are 1 to 10; corresponding $Y$-values are

```
10.631, 18.479, 31.486, 48.778, 69.724, 94.167, 123.812, 157.434, 194.324, 235.911
```

Following my Comment, the point of this demonstration is that, when possible, it is best to
try to discover the true relationship between $Y$'s and $x$'s rather than
treating transformations as 'tricks' to get small residuals. This is
inherently a classical, fully mathematical, small-data approach.

[Modern big-data approaches
favor finding (possibly unknown) relationships that produce optimal predictions.
Very roughly speaking, such approaches are validated by testing each method on 'holdouts' (not used
in finding the relationships) to see how well it works, and on using other
cross-validation methods, much discussed on our sister `stat (cross-validated)` site.]

(1) Regress $Y$ on $x:$
[image]

(2) Regress $Y^2$ on $x^2:$
[image]

(3) Regress $Y^2$ on $x$ and $x^2:$
[image]

(4) Regress $Y$ on $s$ and $x^2;$ this one matches (reasonably well) the model used to make the $Y$'s, and so is the best of the four:
[image]

My model was $Y_i = 5 + 3x_i + 2x_i^2 + e_i,$ with
$e_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0, \sigma=.5).$

Even exploring simple models such as these four, there are several useful criteria for choosing the best model.
The only objective criterion for "best" that is visible in these four figures is
to choose the one with the largest `R-Sq(adj)`.

In this simple example, the variability
in the 'error term' $e$ is quite small relative to the values of $Y$, so it is possible to explain essentially all of the
variability in $Y$-values in terms of regression on $x$ and $x^2.$ You should
not expect such 'perfection' in your own situation.